# command `ll` with wildcard matching is not working as expected

Tags: linux, oh-my-zsh

I am using mac with oh my zsh installed

current omz version

```
➜ omz version                                                                                                          [02/28/22 | 18:49:04]
master (511ed65)
```

I have the following directories in the `node_modules` folder

```
drwxr-xr-x   23 zheng.yuan  1152374831   736B Feb 28 17:00 yaml
drwxr-xr-x   14 zheng.yuan  1152374831   448B Feb 28 17:00 yargs
drwxr-xr-x    8 zheng.yuan  1152374831   256B Feb 28 17:00 yargs-parser
drwxr-xr-x    8 zheng.yuan  1152374831   256B Feb 28 17:00 yn
```

when I run

```
ll node_modules/ya*
```

I expect the output should be something like

```
drwxr-xr-x   23 zheng.yuan  1152374831   736B Feb 28 17:00 yaml
drwxr-xr-x   14 zheng.yuan  1152374831   448B Feb 28 17:00 yargs
drwxr-xr-x    8 zheng.yuan  1152374831   256B Feb 28 17:00 yargs-parser
```

however what. I got is

```
node_modules/yallist:
total 64
-rw-r--r--  1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   765B Feb  6 17:02 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   4.6K Feb  6 17:02 README.md
-rw-r--r--  1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   207B Feb  6 17:02 iterator.js
-rw-r--r--  1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   652B Feb  6 17:02 package.json
-rw-r--r--  1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   8.2K Feb  6 17:02 yallist.js

node_modules/yaml:
total 192
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   743B Feb  6 17:02 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   4.4K Feb  6 17:02 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  13 zheng.yuan  1152374831   416B Feb 28 17:00 browser
drwxr-xr-x  13 zheng.yuan  1152374831   416B Feb 28 17:00 dist
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831    10K Feb  6 17:02 index.d.ts
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831    40B Feb  6 17:02 index.js
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   114B Feb  6 17:02 map.js
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   3.0K Feb  6 17:02 package.json
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   111B Feb  6 17:02 pair.js
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   4.4K Feb  6 17:02 parse-cst.d.ts
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831    51B Feb  6 17:02 parse-cst.js
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   113B Feb  6 17:02 scalar.js
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   311B Feb  6 17:02 schema.js
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   114B Feb  6 17:02 seq.js
drwxr-xr-x   7 zheng.yuan  1152374831   224B Feb 28 17:00 types
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831    11K Feb  6 17:02 types.d.ts
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   510B Feb  6 17:02 types.js
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   578B Feb  6 17:02 types.mjs
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   2.0K Feb  6 17:02 util.d.ts
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   511B Feb  6 17:02 util.js
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   571B Feb  6 17:02 util.mjs

node_modules/yargs:
total 80
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   5.7K Feb  6 17:02 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   1.1K Feb  6 17:02 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   5.5K Feb  6 17:02 README.md
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   234B Feb  6 17:02 browser.mjs
drwxr-xr-x   4 zheng.yuan  1152374831   128B Feb 28 17:00 build
drwxr-xr-x   5 zheng.yuan  1152374831   160B Feb 28 17:00 helpers
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   1.0K Feb  6 17:02 index.cjs
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   233B Feb  6 17:02 index.mjs
drwxr-xr-x   3 zheng.yuan  1152374831    96B Feb 28 17:00 lib
drwxr-xr-x  26 zheng.yuan  1152374831   832B Feb 28 17:00 locales
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   3.0K Feb  6 17:02 package.json
-rw-r--r--   1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   457B Feb  6 17:02 yargs

node_modules/yargs-parser:
total 80
-rw-r--r--  1 zheng.yuan  1152374831    14K Feb  8 19:15 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r--  1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   731B Feb  8 19:15 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 zheng.yuan  1152374831    12K Feb  8 19:15 README.md
-rw-r--r--  1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   1.0K Feb  8 19:15 browser.js
drwxr-xr-x  4 zheng.yuan  1152374831   128B Feb 28 17:00 build
-rw-r--r--  1 zheng.yuan  1152374831   2.3K Feb  8 19:15 package.json
```

I have no idea why suddenly the output starts including the content inside of the folders

I suspect it is related with oh my zsh upgrade but I cannot confirm

Comment: Use `ll -d node_modules/ya*`. The wildcard is expanded by the parent shell before `ll` (actually `/bin/ls -l`) even starts. Demonstrate by putting `echo ` in front of the command.

Comment: Thanks, `ll -d` gave me the expected output, but I was confused why this issue shows up recently, I believe I don't need to add `-d` flag previously.